# Resize top view on listview scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll, resize

I have a layout above a list view which is at the bottom of the main layout.
When i scroll the list, i want to make the top layout smaller. i am trying now to do that using on list view scroll listener and change the layout parameters width and height.
The problem is that this procedure its not smoothly at all, eats a lot of resources.
How can i re-size the top view without using layout parameters (eating a lot of Resources) ?

that the scroll listener I set for the listview:

public class EndLessScrolling implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

```
    private int amountViewInitDimension = 0;

    public EndLessScrolling() {}

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        //amountView on scroll resize effect
        if (firstVisibleItem < 5) {
            View amountView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.select_receiver_amount_parent);

            if (amountView != null) {
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = amountView.getLayoutParams();

                if (amountViewInitDimension == 0) {
                    amountViewInitDimension = params.width;
                }

                params.width = amountViewInitDimension - firstVisibleItem * amountViewInitDimension / 10;
                params.height = amountViewInitDimension - firstVisibleItem * amountViewInitDimension / 10;

                receiverAmount.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, amountTextSize - firstVisibleItem * zoomStep);
                dollarSign.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, dollarSignTextSize - firstVisibleItem * zoomStep / 2f);

                amountView.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please improve your question by adding relevant code needed so the community may be able to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this library? I think is what you want.

https://github.com/carlonzo/StikkyHeader